# Проблема со стартом написания драйвера на Windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, драйвер

Здравствуйте. Попробовал начать писать драйвера на виндовс по гайду ([тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver)) и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой:

```
In the Solution Explorer window, right-click KmdfHelloWorld and choose Add > New Item.
In the Add New Item dialog box, select C++ File. For Name, enter "Driver.c".
```

Но в окошке Add New Item только 1 файл Package Manifest , там нету C++ File.
Может что-то до устанавливать туда надо, не пойму?

Comment: Хм. А вы можете создать обыкновенный хелловорлд на вашей системе?

Comment: Ну короче я в самом верху в Solution нажал Add new item добавил текстовый файл переименовал его в Driver.c копировал туда код из гайда и переместил из Solution items в Source Files Вроде запустилось, правда с ошибку потом какуюто выкинуло, только это как мин неудобно и странно

Comment: Что-то странное, не должно так быть.